# Regular Expression for spaces and hyphens in between words

Tags: regex

I am trying to form a regex to capture both space and hyphen but its not taking the hyphen..any suggestion
Input :

```
578094-131208138004
568315-131208116005
LG506339301
ROTABLE NO 2 BEARING
```

Regex : `/^\w+(\s+\w+)*$/`
If I want to add - its not working in the expression

Answer (score 1):

This will match a single hyphen or space.

```
/[-\s]/
```

This will match multiple spaces and/or hyphens infinitely.

```
/(?:-|\s)(?:-|\s)*/
```

The main reason the second one works is because there's a 'non-captuing group' tacked onto the end. It matches the same thing the first group captures, but it will keep matching multiple matches from a single input. Powerful stuff here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current regex, I think this is what you are looking for:
`^\w+([\s-]+\w+)*$`

Here `[\s-]+` matches any positive number of whitespace symbols or hyphens.

In general this regex will match string beginning and ending with word symbol and having any combination of word symbols, whitespace symbols and hyphens.